# Existe alguma palavra com os 6 diferentes usos do R?

Tags: vocabulário

Enumerei 6 diferentes casos do uso da letra R no português, 5 inicialmente e um sexto caso sugerido nos comentários, os quais representam diferentes sons desta letra, são eles com exemplos:

- **R**ato: Inicio da palavra
- Eleito**R**: Final da palavra
- Co**R**agem: No meio da palavra seguido de vogal
- Fo**RR**o: Duplo (apenas no meio da palavra)
- Insc**R**ito: Precedido de algumas consoantes (não todas)
- Ca**R**ta: No meio de palavras sem vogal

Existe alguma palavra que contenha todos estes usos do R? Ou quais palavras possuem a maior quantidade desses diferentes usos do R?

Exemplos inventados: ***Retrocortarraredor***, ***Recorrentrafircarador***

Comment: tem q ser uma palavra só com R's.. LOL

Comment: O máximo de casos possível numa mesma palavra, vide exemplo

Comment: Não existe um sexto caso, como em «ca**r**ta»?

Comment: @ANeves: Você está certo, inicialmente o considerei similar ao Coragem, mas é um sexto caso. Vou incluí-lo na lista. Obrigado.

Comment: O "r" não tem o mesmo som em "carta" e "eleitor"? A Infopédia usa o mesmo símbolo: "ˈkartɐ", "ilɐjˈtor".

Comment: @stafusa Em qual sotaque? No sotaque paulistano me soam diferentes. Não analisei todos os sotaques.

Comment: @Luciano Interior paulista / norte do Paraná. O 'r' mais "puxado", como se diz, quase caipira.

Comment: Aliás, também pronuncio da mesma forma os 'r's em "rato" e "forro".

Answer (score 2):

Não consigo pensar em uma palavra onde o R se apresente dessas 6 maneiras, mas acho que consegui reunir algumas onde se apresenta de 3/4 formas diferentes.

```
resplandecersuicidar
repercorrer
rerratificar
redemocratizar
```